# Incorrect data received from Socket.ReceiveFrom()

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a UDP server. For test I have a test method `TryMe()` which sends `1:2:Test Device` on my UDP server.
When I trying to get received data, it returns `㨱㨲敔瑳搠癥捩�`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MidiRouter
{
    class Server
    {
        string serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int serverPort = 3005;
        bool isRunning = false;
        Socket listeningSocket;
        public delegate void OnMessageCallback(string remoteAddress, int remotePort, int note, int velocity, string deviceName);
        public OnMessageCallback OnNewMessage;
        public delegate void OnMessageErrorCallback(Exception ex);
        public OnMessageErrorCallback OnMessageError;
        public delegate void OnServerRuntimeErrorCallback(Exception ex);
        public OnServerRuntimeErrorCallback OnServerRuntimeError;

        static Server instance;

        public string ServerAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return serverAddress;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!isRunning)
                {
                    serverAddress = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public int ServerPort
        {
            get
            {
                return serverPort;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!isRunning)
                {
                    serverPort = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public Server()
        {
            instance = this;
            OnNewMessage = noCallBack;
            OnMessageError = noMsgErrors;
            OnServerRuntimeError = noSrvRuntimeErrors;
        }

        void noCallBack(string remoteAddress, int remotePort, int note, int velocity, string deviceName)
        {

        }

        void noMsgErrors(Exception e)
        {

        }

        void noSrvRuntimeErrors(Exception e)
        {

        }

        public bool IsRunning()
        {
            return isRunning;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                listeningSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                Task listeningTask = new Task(Listen);
                listeningTask.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            isRunning = true;
        }

        public void TryMe()
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
ProtocolType.Udp);

            IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse(serverAddress);

            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, serverPort);

            string text = "1:2:Test device";
            byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

            sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);
        }

        static void Listen()
        {
            Server me = instance;
            try
            {
                //Прослушиваем по адресу
                IPEndPoint localIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(me.serverAddress), me.serverPort);
                me.listeningSocket.Bind(localIP);
                int note, velocity;
                while (true)
                {
                    // получаем сообщение
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                    byte[] data = new byte[256]; // буфер для получаемых данных

                    //адрес, с которого пришли данные
                    EndPoint remoteIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = me.listeningSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref remoteIp);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (me.listeningSocket.Available > 0);
                    // получаем данные о подключении
                    IPEndPoint remoteFullIp = remoteIp as IPEndPoint;

                    string fullData = builder.ToString();
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\test.txt", System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\\test.txt") + "\n" + fullData);
                    string[] fullDataSplitted = fullData.Split(':');
                    if (fullDataSplitted.Length < 3)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    List<string> deviceNameSplitted = new List<string>();
                    string deviceName;

                    try
                    {
                        note = Convert.ToInt32(fullDataSplitted[0]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        me.OnMessageError(ex);
                        continue;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        velocity = Convert.ToInt32(fullDataSplitted[1]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        me.OnMessageError(ex);
                        continue;
                    }

                    for (int i = 2; i < fullDataSplitted.Length; i++)
                    {
                        deviceNameSplitted.Add(fullDataSplitted[i]);
                    }

                    deviceName = String.Join(" ", deviceNameSplitted.ToArray());

                    me.OnNewMessage(remoteFullIp.Address.ToString(), remoteFullIp.Port, note, velocity, deviceName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (me.isRunning)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        me.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex1)
                    {

                    }
                    me.OnServerRuntimeError(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            isRunning = false;
            if (listeningSocket != null)
            {
                listeningSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                listeningSocket.Close();
                listeningSocket = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
```

it should use UTF8

```
byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Comment: OP is writing as Encoding.ASCII, but reading as Encoding.Unicode (UTF-16), not Encoding.UTF8. If he would write as ASCII, but read as UTF8 he would have issues as UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. Though you are right that he should write and receive as UTF-8.